# Styled Component Rendering Twice in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've finished this project, it's just that whenever React routes, my home snapshot switch case re-renders a second time.

Here is the code for **Home** page

```html
const Home = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  let recommends = [];
  let newDisneys = [];
  let originals = [];
  let trending = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("movies").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        switch (doc.data().type) {
          case "recommend":
            recommends = [...recommends, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;

          case "new":
            newDisneys = [...newDisneys, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;

          case "original":
            originals = [...originals, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;

          case "trending":
            trending = [...trending, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;
        }
      });

      dispatch(
        setMovies({
          recommend: recommends,
          newDisney: newDisneys,
          original: originals,
          trending: trending,
        })
      );
    });
  }, [userName]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <ImgSlider />
            <Viewers />
            <Recommends />
            <NewDisney />
            <Originals />
            <Trending />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And here is the code for the **App.js** :

```css
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/Nav.jsx'
import Home from './components/Home.jsx';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Detail from './components/Detail';
import Login from './components/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/detail/:id" element={<Detail />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My **Navigation** page:

```js
const Nav = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const userName = useSelector(selectUserName)
    const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
        if (user) {
          setUser(user)
          navigate("/home")
        }
      });
    }, [userName])
  
    const handleAuth = () => {
      if (!userName) {
        auth
          .signInWithPopup(provider)
          .then((result) => {
            setUser(result.user)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message)
          });
      } 
      else if (userName) {
        auth
          .signOut()
          .then(() => {
            dispatch(setSignOutState())
            navigate("/")
          })
          .catch((err) => alert(err.message))
      }
    }
  
    const setUser = (user) => {
      dispatch(
        setUserLoginDetails({
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          photo: user.photoURL,
        })
      );
    };

    return (
        <Header>
            <Logo src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney+" />
            { !userName ? (<Login onClick={handleAuth}>Login</Login>) : (
                <>
                <NavMenu>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <img src="/images/home-icon.svg" alt="Home" />
                    <span>HOME</span>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <img src="/images/search-icon.svg" alt="Search" />
                    <span>SEARCH</span>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/home" href="Watchlist">
                    <img src="/images/watchlist-icon.svg" alt="Watchlist" />
                    <span>WATCHLIST</span>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <img src="/images/original-icon.svg" alt="Originals" />
                    <span>ORIGINALS</span>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <img src="/images/movie-icon.svg" alt="Movies" />
                    <span>MOVIES</span>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <img src="/images/series-icon.svg" alt="Series" />
                    <span>SERIES</span>
                </Link>
            </NavMenu>
            <SignOut>
                <UserImg src={userPhoto} alt={userName}/>
                <DropDown>
                    <span onClick={handleAuth}>Sign Out</span>
                </DropDown>
            </SignOut>
            </>
            )}        
        </Header>
    );
}
```

I'm completely lost as to why it renders my , ,  and  a second time. If I refresh the page, the second render disappears, but once I try to click on a link and use my Nav to route back to the home page, it appears again.

Comment: Turning off Strictmode made it work, how can I make it work without turning off strictmode?

Comment: The point of Strict Mode is to render twice.